# Connecting Teamspeak to Asterisk conference

Tags: voip, asterisk, teamspeak, centos-6.7

I'm trying to connect a [TeamSpeak 3](https://www.teamspeak.com) channel to an [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/) conference (using [ConfBridge](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/ConfBridge)) on [FreePBX](https://www.freepbx.org/).

Not much out there about how to do it. Both the PBX and TS3 servers are running on the same CentOS box. Right now the best approach that I can think of would be to run both clients and pipe the audio between the two, but there must be a better way. Has anyone connected the two successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that TeamSpeak (all versions) use a completely different audio codec and media transport than FreePBX (or asterisk, more specifically).  You would need to do a lot more than "pipe audio between the two".  You would need to transcode the audio in both directions, as well as create a bridge between the container formats.  Creating such a plugin for Asterisk would be relatively simple... but TeamSpeak is proprietary, and trying to do such would violate many licenses, so I doubt you'll find anyone wanting to get into legal-hell trying to build this.

Comment: Actually it shouldn't that hard if you do have the option to use virtual audio devices. You would "just" need to connect those and both should be able to output to an audio device and take input from an audio device. At least in theory that should work and you wouldn't violate either license.